# create an object with same key from a list in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert from:

```
[{skill_1: "java", level_1: 5, skill_2: "js", level_2: 2, skill_3: "docker", level_3: 2}]
```

to:

```
[{name : "java", level:5} , {name : "js", level:2}, {name : "docker", level:2}]
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What is the underlying logic you want to apply to input to get output.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you could use a `for` to get `skill` and `level` from  you object like:

```js
let input = [{skill_1: "java", level_1: 5, skill_2: "js", level_2: 2, skill_3: "docker", level_3: 2}];
let result = [];
let values = Object.values(input)[0];
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  let obj_res = {};
  obj_res.name = values["skill_" + i];
  obj_res.level = values["level_" + i];
  result.push(obj_res);
}
console.log(result);
```

Note: I think the last `level` should be `level_3` and not `level_2`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = [{skill_1: "java", level_1: 5, skill_2: "js", level_2: 2, skill_3: "docker", level_3: 2}];

let res = [];
// iterate object
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(a[0])){
    // string to array
    let ka = k.split("_");
    // check if key already exists in res
    if(res[parseInt(ka[1])-1]){
        // exists
        // assign to dictionary
        res[parseInt(ka[1])-1][ka[0]] = v;
    }else{
        // not exit
        // create dictionary
        res[parseInt(ka[1])-1] = {[ka[0]]: v};
    }
}

console.log(res);
// [
//   { skill: 'java', level: 5 },
//   { skill: 'js', level: 2 },
//   { skill: 'docker', level: 2 }
// ]
```

Hello and welcome to SO, if you are looking for beginner resources, I suggest have a look at [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)